# Facebook API : getUser() always returning 0

Tags: php, facebook, api

this is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

        $appapikey = '453976824647366';
        $appsecret = 'fe86f3b0b34b3ed6eb39bbce717b8062';

        $facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);

        $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
        echo $user_id;



        echo "<p>Hello <fb:name uid=\"$user_id\" useyou=\"false\" linked=\"false\" firstnameonly=\"true\"></fb:name>";
        ?>

    </body>

</head>
</html>
```

Something quite simple but i can't manage to find why getUser is always returning 0
I would appreciate your help!

Comment: It would be nice to mask the api key and secret that way there is no security issue and no unwanted use of the app is done. Unauthorized use may result in to Facebook blocking your account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check would be

```
require_once 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
```

Make sure it is relative to where your php code is rather than to the server structure.

To test this code I would probably just use the existing example provided by Facebook sdk, that way you get it working first by confidently knowing that it really works and can then tweak it as per your needed.
Just pasting it from this link
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '344617158898614',
  'secret' => '6dc8ac871858b34798bc2488200e503d',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The user has to log in first.

After the user logged in (to your site with Facebook) that will show his ID.

Comment: Hum actually the code i provided above in the only one i'm trying to use to get user informations.

So if i understand you right ? i need to make an authentification first ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a) the constructor requires an array of your app's ID and secret, and b) you need to first log the user in.

If you view the page for the Facebook PHP SDK on GitHub, you'll notice after the call to `$facebook->getUser();` they have a section on making API calls, and another section on generating a login or logout URL, depending on if the user is logged in or not.

The flow goes like this:

1. Checks if there's a user in session
2. Tries to get user details
3. If no user, redirect to login URL

When the user comes back to your app, the user will be in session.

Comment: i'm already logged on my own account. So i should be able to see at least my name !

Comment: That may be. But *your* website doesn't know *you* are logged in to Facebook; you need to authenticate first so the SDK knows who 'me' is.